# Indexed DB performance for big amounts of data

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm testing indexeddb to store 10000 elements of 100000 bytes (almost 1Gb).
I see how the browser memory grows until 1 GB. 
Ok, when the process ends, I see browser uses CPU (10-15%)

Chrome ( and FF and Opera ) shutdown !

I test with only 5000 x 100000. Ok, this works and the browser does not reset.
I can see with this test how the files (indexed DB folder) have changed after 20 seconds...

This is not acceptable....

OK, I'm playing with these approach:
close my store & reopen it every 100MB
The problem ? 10 seconds between close - open - first request write success
So ... I have  more time spent that before .....

- oncomplete is not working on chrome
- readwriteflush option works only for FF

Any idea to develop the best approach for write big-data to IndexedDB and force  disk-write ?

Maybe 1 minute for 1GB is good? (A C++ program writes 1GB to file in 20 seconds)